# How to track cursor statements separately in SQL Server extended events?

Tags: sql-server, database-cursor

I want to track statements into SQL Server cursor using extended events but all solutions finding in internet does not work - for example, [this](https://blog.pythian.com/extended-events-fetching-api-cursors/).

Test code:

```sql
DECLARE @objectId int;

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT TOP(3) object_id
FROM sys.tables AS t
ORDER BY object_id;

OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @objectId;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN;
    SELECT @objectId AS object_id;
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
    COMMIT;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @objectId;
END;
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

Comment: Why use cursors in the first place? Unless you want to find them and remove them

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - cursors, like almost any other tool, have their time and place. Can they be used inappropriately? Yes. But so can a hammer.

Comment: @BenThul as almost every question, the reason the cursors are used matters. I suspect they're really used for batch operations, in which case the real operation to track is the batch operations, not the cursors themselves

Comment: Have you tried logging `sqlserver.cursor_manager_*` events? What version of SQL Server do you use?

Comment: SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to track SQL Server cursors and their inner statements by using extended events, you have these events to choose from the library:

1. sqlserver.cursor_manager_* events
   Use them for capturing **TSQL** Cursor
2. sqlserver.cursor_* events
   Use them for capturing **API** Cursor

In your example, you are using the **TSQL cursor.**

---

Here is an example Extended Events Session script to capture **TSQL Cursor** open/close events.
It will capture events fired by the TSQL cursor declared in your test code.

***NOTE:*** I also had to capture event **sqlserver.sql_statement_completed**, in order to get the statement executed from within the cursor.

```sql
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Track_tsql_cursor] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.cursor_manager_cursor_end( 
    ACTION( 
        sqlserver.client_app_name, 
        sqlserver.database_name, 
        sqlserver.is_system, 
        sqlserver.session_id, 
        sqlserver.sql_text) 
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[database_name]=N'...') 
), 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.cursor_manager_cursor_begin( 
    ACTION( 
        sqlserver.client_app_name, 
        sqlserver.database_name, 
        sqlserver.is_system, 
        sqlserver.query_hash, 
        sqlserver.session_id, 
        sqlserver.sql_text) 
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[database_name]=N'...') 
), 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_completed( 
    ACTION( 
        sqlserver.client_app_name, 
        sqlserver.database_name, 
        sqlserver.is_system, 
        sqlserver.query_hash, 
        sqlserver.session_id, 
        sqlserver.sql_text) 
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[database_name]=N'...') 
) 
WITH ( 
    MAX_MEMORY=16384 KB, 
    MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=10 SECONDS, 
    TRACK_CAUSALITY=ON 
); 
GO
```

Here are the results from your test query (tested on SQL Server 2019 and 2014):

[image: Track_tsql_cursor results]